# Android on Eclipse crashes every time I open main.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, adt

I have ADT loaded onto classic Eclipse. I followed the steps from the Android Helloworld starting guide located here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

The problem happens every time I load up main.xml. It appears to be a problem with the ADT plugin as it relates to the GUI layout editor it has (the one that creates XML in the background). If I access the XML source directly, it doesn't crash.

I've gotten different error messages, out of memory, no exit information, and "exception in checkandloadtargetdata permgen space". If you have any questions about my setup, feel free to post them in comments and I'll update the thread.

I'm running windows 7 x64 bit with a fairly clean install. I've also got JDK 1.6. Here's the text from Eclipse's .log file located in .metadata. Any help would be appreciated.

```
!SESSION 2011-08-14 13:11:38.628 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -debug -console -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2011-08-14 13:11:51.038
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.getView(ViewReference.java:198)

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2011-08-14 13:11:51.043
!MESSAGE Exception in checkAndLoadTargetData.
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2011-08-14 13:11:51.056
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2700)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-08-14 13:13:59.256
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2011-08-14 13:13:59.263
!MESSAGE Parsing Data for android-7 failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

After trying the below eclipse.ini settings

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

I now get something new, I since main.xml is already "opened" if I open Eclipse all the way, and just let it churn for a few seconds without doing anything, the GUI editor comes up and seems to be working fine. If I click on anything else (Like the tab for HelloAndroid.java) then it locks up, and crashes.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the SDK, deleted my Eclipse install, and reinstalled everything.

Notable things I changed.

-I moved the Eclipse install out of the program files directory, as I know Windows treats that one differently. It's now in C:/Eclipse

-I moved the Android SDK out of the program files directory, for the same reasons, and made sure there were no spaces in the path. It's now in C:/androidSDK/

Seems to be working fine, now. I wonder if it was a conflict between eclipse being in one of the program files directory and the SDK being in the other. I don't know if windows boots those programs differently based on which directory they're in. In any case, if you're having an issue like this, move them out of the program files directory.

Comment: As far as my experience goes, this happens when you install some EE plugins onto the same Eclipse as the Android plugin, and if to be more specific, this also happened to me after only installing the JavaScript plugin!

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to increase PermGen size. There is an article on [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse?). 1024m would be enough. 
Anyway, my eclipse.ini should help too.

```
cat /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: Actually now it lets me open Eclipse, with main.xml already opened on the toolbar, and the GUI editor appears to be working fine. It now crashes when I try to go to another tab.

Comment: It is odd, seems something goes wrong and you runs out of memory. I only can advice to run eclipse with -clean flag, clean the project, uninstall extra plugins, reinstall eclipse or windows or install linux;) And look at your xml file, maybe it has some errors and eclipse can't parse it properly. And after increasing PermGen do you still have OutOfMemoryError exception or something else?

Comment: When I tried to google something I noticed that OutOfMemoryErrors appeared in earlier versions of eclipse and adt plugins. So this issue looks more like a bug than your fault.

Answer (score 4):

You have to upgrade your jdk version to the latest version.I found most of the cases online is that the jdk5 made the eclipse crashed and they worked out by upgrade to jdk6. I used jdk6 but the problem existed! At last I download the [latest version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html)(jdk7) and the eclipse not crashes any more!

Answer (score 0):

After trying the answers in this post. This worked for me on Windows 7 x64 bit and  JDK 1.7 - delete the troublesome Eclipse (Mars Java + ADT) and reinstall. I made no changes to the PermSize, but I do have -Xms512m -Xmx1024m in the eclipse.ini file. The original workspace loaded OK too.